# Почему 'weekday' не преобразуется в столбец из индекса?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = pd.read_csv('/datasets/real_estate_data.csv', sep = '\t')
data['price_sqmeter'] = data['last_price'] / data['total_area']
data['first_day_exposition'] = pd.to_datetime(data['first_day_exposition'], format = '%Y-%m-%d')
data['days_exposition']=data['days_exposition'].fillna(data.groupby('first_day_exposition')['days_exposition'].transform('mean'))
data['weekday'] = data['first_day_exposition'].dt.weekday
data['month'] = data['first_day_exposition'].dt.month
data['year'] = data['first_day_exposition'].dt.year
data['week'] = data['first_day_exposition'].dt.week
data.sort_values(by = ['weekday'], ascending = False).reset_index(drop = False)
for n in [5,13,28,37,45,50]:
    plt.plot(data[(data['week']==n)&(data['year']==2017)]['price_sqmeter'].groupby('weekday').mean())
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то, что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: @MaxU, когда я оставляю в reset_index(drop = False) - появляется ошибка - cannot insert level_0, already exists
А если изменяю False на True, то просто 'weekday'

Comment: предвидя это, я попросил привести в вопросе  [воспроизводимый пример входных данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1230875/%d0%92-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-weekday-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%86-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b0?noredirect=1#comment2156646_1230875)

Comment: непонятно зачем вам вообще `.reset_index(...)`??

Comment: @MaxU, мне, при выполнении этого условия, всегда выводило ошибку KeyError: 'weekday', хотя до этого всё было в порядке, поэтому подумал, что через reset_index() удастся исправить ошибку.



   ' for n in [5,13,28,37,45,50]:
        plt.plot(data[(data['week']==n)&(data['year']==2017)]['price_sqmeter'].groupby('weekday').mean())
        plt.show()'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[DataFrame.sort_values()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) - возвращает отсортированный DataFrame, но не меняет при этом исходный фрейм, поэтому попробуйте так:

```
data = data.sort_values(by = ['weekday'], ascending = False).reset_index(drop = False)
```